# Split python object into two objects

Tags: python

I have an object that looks like

```
object = [{'number':'230/600','blah':'hi'},{'number':'240/620','blah':'hey'}]
```

which I want to split into the following format

```
[{'first':'230','second':'600', 'blah':'hi'},{'first':'240','second':'620','blah':'hey'}]
```

Any tips on how to do that split based off of what comes before and after the `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format is fixed, you can do this:

```
>>> object = [{'number':'230/600'},{'number':'240/620'}]

>>> for value in object:
...     numbers = value['number'].split('/')
...     new_object.append({'numbera': numbers[0], 'numberb': numbers[1]})
...

>>> new_object
[{'numberb': '600', 'numbera': '230'}, {'numberb': '620', 'numbera': '240'}]
>>>
```

Edit: This was before the question was edited. Mike's answer works great for the edited question.

Comment: what if there is another element in the data that doesn't change but should be in the new one? See edits. For instance `object = [{'number':'230/600','blah':'hi'},{'number':'240/620','blah':'hey'}]`

Comment: @nquestion you can clone the list `object` with [:] like `foo = object[:]` **EDIT:** this was for you comment before you edit it.

Comment: @Eekan So could I just do `new_object.append({'numbera': numbers[0], 'numberb': numbers[1],'blah': value['blah']})` to grab that `blah` element?

Comment: @nquestion yes, and by the way `new_object` wasn't defined in that code so you should bind it with empty list `[]`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
res = []
for item in L:
    d = {}
    for key, value in item.items():
        split_value = value.split('/')
        if len(split_value) > 1:
            for entry, name in zip(split_value, ['first', 'second']):
                d[name] = entry
        else:
            d[key] = value
    res.append(d)
```

Now:

```
>>> res
[{'blah': 'hi', 'first': '230', 'second': '600'},
 {'blah': 'hey', 'first': '240', 'second': '620'}]
```

Comment: What's the `abc` part about?

Comment: @nquestion: For `numbera`, `numberb`, and `numberc`.  Take a look at the documentation for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: `abc` are the letters that will be added to `number` to form `numbera` etc. If you have more than three elements to split, you need more letters. `string.ascii_lowercase` could be useful here.

Comment: The shortest one wins. There are only two entries in the split string. So only `a` and `b` are used.

Comment: But is the letter part redundant given my edits above `[{'first':'230','second':'600', 'blah':'hi'},{'first':'240','second':'620','blah':'hey'}]`

Comment: Updated my answer.